# Adding an ID column in a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I have a list of XML files that I am merging together, but I am trying to figure out how to add an `"id"` column to each data frame based on the file name.

```
# BUILD DATAFRAME LIST
list_filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".xml$")

df_list <- lapply(list_filenames, function(f) {

  list_ids <- as.list(list_filenames)

  doc  <- xmlParse(f, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
  doc2 <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//Event"))
  mapply(cbind, doc2, "id" = list_ids, SIMPLIFY = F)  # Code that kind of works

  })

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

I'm hoping to get something that looks like this:

```
ex_df <- cbind(x = c(3, 2, 10, 12),
               y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
               id = c("file_name_1", "file_name_1", "file_name_2", "file_name_2")) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

> ex_df
   x y          id
1  3 a file_name_1
2  2 b file_name_1
3 10 c file_name_2
4 12 d file_name_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
nm1 <- sub("\\.xml$", "", list_filenames)
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, df_list, id = nm1))
```

---

In the OP's code, we are looping over the `list_filenames` and then in the second line, using the full set of `list_filenames` in

```
as.list(list_filenames)
```

Instead it would be just 'f' i.e

```
df_list <- lapply(list_filenames, function(f) {

  list_id <- sub("\\.xml$", "", f) #####

  doc  <- xmlParse(f, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
  doc2 <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//Event"))
  doc2$id = list_id
  doc2

  })
```

Then, we could `rbind` the `list elements

```
 do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: @Marshall i think the updated explanation may help you iin understanding why your function didn't work